# (History) Who first solved the Schroedinger equation for the hydrogen-like atom (Coulomb potential)?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, history, hydrogen

My sense was that it was Pauli, but I can't seem to find any evidence to support this.

Comment: Welcome to physics SE. Its better if you ask this question in the [hsm.se].

Comment: For such "pure" history question, you might better consider [hsm.SE].

Comment: Schroedinger himself, 1926, see http://www.physics.drexel.edu/~bob/Quantum_Papers/Schr_1.pdf, http://www.physics.drexel.edu/~bob/Quantum_Papers/Schr_2.pdf, http://www.physics.drexel.edu/~bob/Quantum_Papers/QAEP3.pdf, http://www.physics.drexel.edu/~bob/Quantum_Papers/QAEP4.pdf

Comment: Pauli solved the quantum Coulomb problem using Heisenberg's version of quantum mechanics, not the Schoedinger equation, as far as I know.

Comment: Read section 9 of [this](http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~hooft101/lectures/lieg07.pdf). Of course it was Pauli. Of course he had no *need* for the  Schroedinger equation.  That is the whole point of matrix methods: you are not captive of differential equations.

Comment: @CosmasZachos However valuable Pauli's approach, the OP question is "Who first solved the Schroedinger equation for the hydrogen-like atom". If Pauli had no need for the Schroedinger equation, he didn't solve it, did he now?

Comment: @udrv Of course you are right on these facts! But his question and proposed answer *only* make sense tweaked as: "who got the Hydrogen spectrum first?", which he might not appreciate does *not require* solving the Schr eqn; the misconception that solving diff eqns is the heart of the matter is all but universal in poor introductory QM courses.

Comment: @CosmasZachos Perhaps, but then again, it is so often left out that Schroedinger did a lot more in his 4 papers than just postulate his equation. He solved and verified it on the standard textbook examples that make up those intro courses to this day. No spin though, and Pauli keeps his share regardless.

Comment: @udvr Couldn't agree more. But a teachable moment is harsh to forfeit...

Comment: Thanks all--yes, it seems the literature attributes Pauli and Schroedinger variously.  Thanks for all the insight!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about physics, it is about history. As noted in the [site guidelines for history questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8930), questions that are exclusively about the history of physics should be asked on [hsm.se].

Comment: As far as I know, Schrödinger only showed that both methods produced the same energies. He did not show that the matrix method can produce the electron orbitals, which I don't think it can.

Answer (score 4):

The solution is in Schroedinger's first paper on wave mechanics --- but believe it was Herman Weyl who did the Laguerre Polynomial math. Weyl  lived almost next door to Schrodinger and was Schroedinger's wifes lover at the time.

A good account is in "Schrödinger: Life and Thought" by Walter Moore.

Comment: This is not a question of belief. In his article Schrödinger thanks Weyl for the instructions for solving the equation.

Answer (score 3):

Pauli was indeed the first who solved the quantum-mechanical problem of the hydrogen spectrum.

His [article](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01450175) was submitted on 17.01.1926. The [article](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/andp.19263840404) of Schrödinger was submitted 10 days later.

However Pauli did not solve the Schrödinger equation (no wonder - the equation was not yet known to the scientific community). He solved the problem using the matrix version of the quantum mechanics due to Heisenberg-Born-Jordan.

By the way it was Schrödinger who first [proved](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/andp.19263840804) that the both versions of quantum mechanics are equivalent.

Comment: No, this is wrong, Schroedinger did not show equivalence of wave mechanics and matrix mechanics. He only showed that starting with his equation, he could reach the matrix equations, but not viceversa.

Comment: @DanielC Schrödinger claimed that he proved "viceversa" in §4 of his article. If his proof is flawed just point out his error.

Comment: I will look it up and come back.